# Fastest way to sorted eigenvalues and eigenvectors in Julia

Tags: julia

I would like to know the fastest way to obtain sorted (ascending/descending) real eigenvalues in julia.

as an example:

```
a = [0.5 0 0.0;0  0.3 0; 0.0 0  0.2]
w,v = eigen(a)
```

How can I sort the results with ascending/descending order of the eigenvalues?

Can `eigen` already sort the results? If so, how?

Best Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried it? It already does sort the values. [Reference](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/#LinearAlgebra.eigen):

> By default, the eigenvalues and vectors are sorted lexicographically by `(real(λ),imag(λ))`. A different comparison function `by(λ)` can be passed to `sortby`, or you can pass `sortby=nothing` to leave the eigenvalues in an arbitrary order. Some special matrix types (e.g. `Diagonal` or `SymTridiagonal`) may implement their own sorting convention and not accept a sortby keyword.

To get the inverse order, you can pass `sortby = -` (for reals, at least).